# How are citizens of Elysium arrested?

Tags: robots, elysium

The robots on Elysium cannot arrest a citizen. As stated by a robot at the end of the movie.

So who deals with criminals who happen to be citizens? Is the movie implying that the super rich are incapable of committing a crime? Surely the super rich are still super likely to do super stupid illegal things.

If there is a human police force onstation, will the robots allow a citizen to be detained? Or will they try defend them from 'harm', especially if the citizen resits arrest. How would the robot recognise a lawful backyard punch-up between neighbours to someone trying to avoid a lawful arrest?

What about a citizen onplanet. If they do something blatantly against the law, the robot will just stand by and watch? Probably even help out, to defend the citizen from the lowly mob?

Comment: Nice! Good question!

Comment: I think the implication is more like "The super-rich are above the law".

Comment: @Joe L. Except the defense secretary is afraid that she will be arrested for treason. So who wouldarrest her?

Comment: As for the last question, I was under the impression that citizens did not go down to the planet. Didn't Jodie Foster's character go down and wanted to hide the fact because it was illegal or something? Admittedly, the movie wasn't that memorable so I might have the details wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the movie implying that the super rich are incapable of committing a crime?

Perhaps not literally incapable, but simply that they're considered to be 'above the law'. This would be consistent with the portrayal of society in *Elysium*: the super-rich are so privileged that they can even break the law without fear of retribution. Arresting a citizen of Elyisum would be considered akin to arresting the Queen in today's United Kingdom - almost by definition, they can do no wrong.

Comment: That would make sense for the 'minor' major crimes. But what about treason? The defense minister was scared of being arrested for treason. She even says so in the movie rather than letting it be implied....and surely if a crime is committed against a citizen that citizen would likely want retribution...