# How can police droids arrest these people?

Tags: elysium

### How can the police droids arrest the forged illegals that land on Elysium at the start of the movie?

The question [How are citizens of Elysium arrested?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142188/how-are-citizens-of-elysium-arrested) really got me thinking.

We are told that the droids cannot arrest a citizen and we are shown this when the president tells the droids to arrest Spider:

So we are shown how Spider hacks the system and makes "EVERYONE" a citizen, but in the beginning scene when the illegals land on Elysium, they have forged documents and as far as we can tell the droids cannot tell the difference.

So how can the droids arrest these people when by all accounts they are considered a citizen by the **"System"** which runs the droids?

Comment: It's possible this sophisticated system has factored illegal forging and given the illegals arrived on transports that were no doubt tracked as they entered the territory, the droids were sent to recover anyone leaving the unauthorized vessels, whether or not they pass the citizen validation. When Spider forces a reboot, maybe those protocols were wiped... or new orders were sent in the program since it was written for coup purposes. The programmers may have factored that a coup would be detected and thus, coded accordingly

Comment: @KaiQing, at the very start we are told that droids cannot arrest a citizen, so it is not a new protocol. As for the down voter , how on earth does this question deserve a DV? How about you add a comment as to what needs to be done to make it better?

Comment: It could be considered a succinct generalization that they cannot arrest a citizen for no reason. Does that rule apply if a citizen decides to murder someone? Surely just being a citizen of elysium doesn't automatically put them above all laws. It makes sense that a med bay doesn't have any distinction between authentic and illegals, but the security is probably not so simple. All speculation I guess, but assuming the rule is a blanket "no elysium citizens can be arrested" would be a massive flaw in design

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the film's screenplay. The computer is tracking the arrival of the ship, which it notes to be an illegal vessel. It then follows the *individual arrivals* and captures them systematically. We can assume that it's not looking at their personal status (as would-be citizens), but just acting on the principle that anyone who's entitled to be there wouldn't have come on an illegal transport.

> INT. IMMIGRANT SHIP
>   Throngs of illegal immigrants. The MOTHER strokes her DAUGHTER'S hair. Coke bottles and garbage float in zero G. The FATHER and his YOUNG SON lie waiting to land.
>
> NUN (V.O.): But it's illegal, they don't like us there.
>
> EXT. ELYSIUM - DAY
>   As the ship pulls up to the surface...
>
> INT. PROTOCOL ROOM
>   A very high-tech cylindrical room on the inside of Elysium. A tiny scroll of text blinks on a computer monitor:
>   **ILLEGAL ENTRY. DISPATCHING HOMELAND DEFENSE.**
>
> EXT. ELYSIUM - DAY
>   The graffitied ship touches down. The back bay doors open and
>   the immigrants emerge. The MOTHER helps her sick DAUGHTER out
>   onto the lawn of this new utopia.
>
> NUN (V.O.) So they send us home...
>
> The immigrants see HELICOPTER-LIKE VEHICLES dotting the skies, getting closer, filled with IMMIGRATION POLICE DROIDS. The immigrants run for their lives. The father and son get
>   caught, as a droid fires a net over them, trapping them.

Note also that there's no real punishment here, just capture and release back to approximately where the immigrants came from.